# Animate noise on Android

Tags: android, android-animation, noise

I want to do some "mist effect" with Perlin 3D noise, the Z axis for number of animation frame.

I'm using a grid of 16x9 LinearLayouts for this, all of them with the same background color, and changing their alpha transparency to the values of Perlin noise.

Works quite well on my tablet, but with 32x18 things begin to crawl a bit, and on my phone I see nothing, just some artifacts - like random image tearing.

Would a custom view and drawing directly on canvas (then upsizing the whole thing) be faster and safer?

Or is the problem generating 3D noise so fast while updating screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing directly into canvas is the appropriate way to do it. No more "artifact" problems, and way better framerate. It's also very easy to do.

Here's a working example of a `MistView` class:

```
package com.example.yourapp; // don't forget to change this

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.Random;

public class MistView extends View {

    SimplexNoise sN = new SimplexNoise(); // you'll need a working SimplexNoise class
    Paint[][] paints = null;
    float floathex[][];
    final static int W = 32;
    final static int H = 18;
    float widthf, heightf;
    int z = 0;
    final static int R = 128; // you can play with color here
    final static int G = 128;
    final static int B = 128;
    Random rand = new Random();
    final int xoff = random(-100000, 100000);
    final int yoff = random(-100000, 100000);
    final int zoff = random(-100000, 100000);
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            z++;
            reDraw();
        }
    };

    public MistView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.paints = new Paint[W][H];
        for (int w = 0; w < W; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < H; h++)
            {
                this.paints[w][h] = new Paint();
                this.paints[w][h].setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            }
        }
    }

    public MistView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this.paints = new Paint[W][H];
        for (int w = 0; w < W; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < H; h++)
            {
                this.paints[w][h] = new Paint();
                this.paints[w][h].setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        if (widthf == 0)
            widthf = canvas.getWidth() / (float) W;
        if (heightf == 0)
            heightf = canvas.getHeight() / (float) H;
        floathex = sN.generateOctavedSimplexNoise(W, H, z, xoff, yoff, zoff, 8, 0.05f, 0.05f);

        for (int w = 0; w < W; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < H; h++)
            {
                int a = Math.round(64* ((floathex[w][h] + 1f)/2f));
                if (a < 0)
                    a = 0;
                this.paints[w][h].setColor(Color.argb(a, R, G, B));
                canvas.drawRect(w * widthf, h * heightf, (w + 1) * widthf, (h + 1) * heightf, this.paints[w][h]);
            }
        }
        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 60);
    }

    protected void reDraw() {
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int random(int min, int max) {
        return (int) (rand.nextFloat() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
 }
```